# I want to create a custom check box which toggles between label and image

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, mxml, flex-spark

I want to create a custom reusable component by extending a spark Button class so that it has a checkbox and a label which says Show Image. When checkbox is selected an image will be displayed instead of the label. The Image path should be exposed as an API. How can we extend spark.components.Button to have it check box with labe or image (image path should be dynamic).

I tried to extend Button class as below but not sure how to create check box in it and how to pass image path as parameter to that.

```
package myClasses
{
    import spark.components.Button;

    public class ImageCheckBox extends Button
    {
        public function ImageButton()
        {
            super();
            this.buttonMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the custom components something like below in application.

```
<myClasses:ImageCheckBox skinClass="mySkins.HelpButtonSkin" path="...."" label="Show Image" />
```

Comment: Create view states http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html

Comment: I want to use it as a reusable component where I can pass the image path dynamically to this component wherever I use it.

Comment: I think you don't need to extend from Button. Extend from SkinnableComponent and create skin for this component. And in skin you declare skin parts (checkBox, Label, Image)

Comment: I agree with Anton. The right way (due to spark architecture) is to create own component with needed skin parts and skin states and implement default skin for it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
package myClasses {
import flash.events.Event;

import spark.components.CheckBox;
import spark.components.Image;
import spark.components.Label;
import spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableComponent;

public class ImageCheckBox extends SkinnableComponent {
    [SkinPart(required=true)]
    public var checkBox:CheckBox;

    [SkinPart(required=true)]
    public var labelComp:Label;

    [SkinPart(required=true)]
    public var image:Image;

    private var pathChanged:Boolean = false;
    private var _path:String;
    public function get path():String {
        return _path;
    }

    public function set path(value:String):void {
        if (_path != value) {
            _path = value;
            pathChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }
    }

    private var labelChanged:Boolean = false;
    private var _label:String;
    public function get label():String {
        return _label;
    }

    public function set label(value:String):void {
        if (_label != value) {
            _label = value;
            labelChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }
    }

    public function ImageCheckBox() {
        super();
        setStyle("skinClass", ImageCheckBoxSkin);
    }

    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);

        if (instance == checkBox) {
            checkBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkBoxChangeHandler)
        }
        else if (instance == labelComp) {
            labelComp.text = label;
        }
        else if (instance == image) {
            image.source = path;
        }
    }

    override protected function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
        super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

        if (instance == checkBox) {
            checkBox.removeEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkBoxChangeHandler)
        }
    }

    override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String {
        return checkBox.selected ? "selected" : super.getCurrentSkinState();
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void {
        if (labelChanged) {
            labelChanged = false;
            labelComp.text = label;
        }

        if (pathChanged) {
            pathChanged = false;
            image.source = path;
        }

        super.commitProperties();
    }

    private function checkBoxChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
        invalidateSkinState();
    }
}}
```

And skin

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[
    /**
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("myClasses.ImageCheckBox")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="selected"/>
</s:states>

<s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="3">
    <s:CheckBox id="checkBox"
                verticalCenter="0"
                height="100%"/>
    <s:Label id="labelComp"
             verticalCenter="0" verticalAlign="middle"
             width="100%" height="100%"
             visible.normal="true" includeInLayout.normal="true"
             visible.selected="false" includeInLayout.selected="false"/>
    <s:Image id="image"
             verticalCenter="0"
             width="100%" height="100%"
             fillMode="scale" scaleMode="letterbox"
             visible.normal="false" includeInLayout.normal="false"
             visible.selected="true" includeInLayout.selected="true"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Actually, extending the spark.components.Button is my requirement.